# get function parameter with default value

Tags: php, reflection

i know how to get function parameters.

I am using of course ReflectionMethod to get function parameters but currently i am not able to get default value of those parameter.

this is my code where function is defined

```
class A{
    public function fn($para1,$para2="not required"){
            //some kind of stuff
    }
}
```

code for getting function parameter

```
$meth = new ReflectionMethod("A","fn");
foreach ($meth->getParameters() as $param) {
    //some kind of stuff   
}
```

now please tell how do i get default value of function parameter

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.reflectionparameter.php
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reflectionparameter.getdefaultvalue.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

```
<?php
function foo($test, $bar = 'baz')
{
    echo $test . $bar;
}

$function = new ReflectionFunction('foo');

foreach ($function->getParameters() as $param) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $param->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    if ($param->isOptional()) {
        echo 'Default value: ' . $param->getDefaultValue() . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getdefaultvalue.php

Comment: but how can i access function which is inside class?

Comment: It is the same way, try getDefaultValue() in your posted foreach block. You got the $param value like in the example so `$param->getDefaultValue()` will show you defaut parameter of method `fn` in class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can find the answer quite easily.

```
$meth = new ReflectionMethod("A","fn");
foreach ($meth->getParameters() as $param) {
        var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($param)));
}
```

This will print a list of all available methods, and here are the last few:

```
[11]=> string(10) "isOptional"
[12]=> string(23) "isDefaultValueAvailable"
[13]=> string(15) "getDefaultValue"
```

This should give you enough information to figure out the answer. That is, before going to the manual.